# Create a new data frame of the means of randomly selected rows - looped

Tags: r, function, dataframe, subset, random

**Question:**

I have a data.frame (hlth) that consists of 49 vectors - a mix of numeric(25:49) and factor(1:24). I am trying to randomly select 50 rows, then calculate column means only for the numeric columns (dropping the other values), and then place the random row mean(s) into a new data.frame (beta). I would then like to iterate this process 1000 times.

I have attempted this process but the values that get returned are identical and the new means will not enter the new data.frame

**Here is a few rows and columns of the data.frame(hlth)**

`DateIn    adgadj    Sex  VetMedCharges    pwtfc
  1/01/2006 3.033310  STEER          0.00 675.1151
  1/10/1992 3.388245  STEER       2540.33 640.2261
  1/10/1995 3.550847  STEER        572.78 607.6200
  1/10/1996 2.893707 HEIFER        549.42 425.5217
  1/10/1996 3.647233  STEER        669.18 403.8238`

**The code I have used thus far:**

```
set.seed[25]
beta<-data.frame()

net.row<-function(n=50){
 netcol=sample(1:nrow(hlth),size=n ,replace=TRUE)
 rNames <- row.names(hlth)
 subset(hlth,rNames%in%netrow,select=c(25:49))
 colMeans(s1,na.rm=TRUE,dims=1)
 }

 beta$net.row=replicate(1000,net.row()); net.row
```

The two issues, that I have detected, are:

1) Returns the same value(s) each iteration

2) "Error during wrap-up: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" when the beta$netrow

Any suggestions would be appreciated!!!

Comment: `netcol=sample(1:nrow(hlth),size=n ,replace=TRUE)` should presumably by `netrow = ...` and the error is a scoping problem - R is trying to subset the function `beta`, presumably again, because it can't find `netRowMeans` in the `data.table` you've defined, moves on to the global environment and throws an error there.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to my comment (and firstly pasting it):

`netcol=sample(1:nrow(hlth),size=n ,replace=TRUE)` should presumably by `netrow = ...` and the error is a scoping problem - R is trying to subset the function `beta`, presumably again, because it can't find `netRowMeans` in the `data.frame` you've defined, moves on to the global environment and throws an error there.

There are also a couple of other things. You don't assign `subset(hlth,rNames%in%netrow,select=c(25:49))` to a variable, which I think you mean to assign to `s1`, so `colMeans` is probably running on something you've set in the global environment.

If you want to pass a variable directly in to the data frame `beta` in that manner, you'll have to initialise `beta` with the right number of columns and number of rows - the column means you've passed out will be a vector of `(1 x 25)`, so won't fit in a single column. You would probably be better of initalising a matrix called `mat` or something (to avoid confusion with scoping errors masking the actual error messages) with `25` columns and `1000` rows.

EDIT: Question has been edited slightly since I posted this, but most points still stand.